# Unbundling how subtracting a range from an integer works in Rust

Tags: rust, range

A listing in [Chapter 13-04](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-04-performance.html) of the Rust Book features the following for loop:

```rust
for i in 12..buffer.len() {
    let prediction = coefficients
        .iter()
        .zip(&buffer[i - 12..i])
        .map(|(&c, &s)| c * s as i64)
        .sum::<i64>()
}
```

I understand what this does except for the "i - 12..i" bit. I didn't know you can subtract a range from an integer and get ... another range back?

I used the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13a95ca98df21f52305e1969793e4e4f) to see how this syntax works empirically:

```rust
println!("\"3 - 3..4\": {:?}", 3 - 3..4);
println!("\"3 - 3..3\": {:?}", 3 - 3..3);
println!("\"3 - 3..2\": {:?}", 3 - 3..2);
println!("\"3 - 3..1\": {:?}", 3 - 3..1);
println!("\"3 - 3..0\": {:?}", 3 - 3..0);
```

Which prints:

```
"3 - 3..4": 0..4
"3 - 3..3": 0..3
"3 - 3..2": 0..2
"3 - 3..1": 0..1
"3 - 3..0": 0..0
```

Therefore, a naive answer would be that subtracting a range from an integer will yield a range that starts from zero and ends with the difference between the integer and the length (positive or negative) of the range.

Is that a good explanation? What is the the trait in [std::ops::Range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html) that makes this syntax possible?

Comment: Just a tip: you can use `dbg!(...)` macro to avoid repetition. E.g. `dbg!(3 - 3..4)` which outputs: `3 - 3..4 = 0..4`

Comment: Oh, good to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence), which defines what operators bind more strongly than others when there is a lack of parentheses, i.e. if you write `a + b * c` is it interpreted as `(a + b) * c` or `a + (b * c)`.

In this case you're just using minus and range, but the question is the same, so is `a - b..c` interpreted as `(a - b)..c` or `a - (b..c)`? It's the former. So when you write `3 - 3..4` it is interpreted as `(3 - 3)..4`, which is why that results in a range going from `0..4`.

---

If you try to explicitly wrap parentheses around the range like `3 - (3..4)`, then the compiler will error saying that `Sub<Range<{integer}>> for {integer}` is actually not implemented in the first place.

When in doubt, wrap an operation in parentheses.